# plugin manager: plugin is disabled or ACL protected: juser

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am attempting to embed a Fabrik form in an article, the article displays fine without the form, however as soon as I embed it I get the below error.

```
plugin manager: plugin is disabled or ACL protected: juser
```

I have googled it and haven't come up with a similar error message, so I'm a bit stumped as to what is causing it. I have checked the fabrik plugins (including the content plugin) and these are all published.

The error can be seen [here](https://sitewidedesign.co.uk/ptbnew/index.php/en/wholesale)

Any suggestions as to what I can do to try and identify/rectify the issue?

Regards
Donna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the Access level of the content plugin? A similar issue was seen here on the Fabrik forum. http://fabrikar.com/forums/index.php?threads/error-message-with-email-list-plugin-after-upgrade.47175/#post-244488.

I that's not it, I would suggest to create a thread on the Fabrik forum, they have great community support and are quick to respond.

Comment: Hi Paul, are you a member of the fabrik forum? I cannot create an account as their captcha is using V1 nor can I find an email address to contact them. I have tweeted them but no response. So I cannot ask a question in the forum and have no way to let them know the registration form does not work.

Comment: I see what you are saying and created a post in the forum, i'll keep yo posted as soon as I hear something.

Comment: Hi Donna, that should be fixed now.